# pushing ajax json responses in array

Tags: arrays, jquery, push, response

I try to iterate throug an array of ids and make a ajax request for each id. subsequentely each response object is pushed in an array/ so far no problem, however, the problem starts when i try to access the responses in the array. the strange thing is that in the console log the responses are shown (ouside the array though, see below) but the properties of the array objects are empty/ it seems i generated an empty object with some data attached to it/ my question is how can i access the objects that are in (or not in?) the array

```
    var getAssoc = {
        returnProds: function (idCache) {
            var id = idCache;
            var prodData = [];
            var counter = id.length;
            $.each(id, function (i) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "myurl.php?",
                    data: {
                        'id': id[i]
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        prodData[i] = data;
                            counter--;
                            if (counter === 0) console.log(prodData);
                    },                  
                })
            }); 
        }
    };
```

console log looks like this. testing for number of properties returns 0

[]
0 Object { array={...}}
 
1 Object { array={...}}
2 Object { array={...}}
3 Object { array={...}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you success callback Try parsing the response coming from your server:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: thanks martin for your quick reply/ that results in the proberties of the response objects in the array to be "null"/ by the way the dataType is jsonp which i specified in $.ajaxSetup

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` show you in your success function?

Comment: that would be "[], 0 Object {null}, 1 Object {null}, 2 Object {null}, 3 Object {null}"; i am also interested if and how i might be able to access the objects which are shown in the console log of my initial post/ since the data i am after are show in the log when i click on the objects in firebug, there might be a way to access them. however, since the parent object is testable empty, i do not know how i should do that

Comment: i think i understand what the problem is. i tried to push a multidimensional data structure in a one dimensional array. that is probably not a good idea. my plan was to structure the array further in another section. what seems to work though is that when i push the data responses directly in an 3 dimensional array. what i am still curious about is that although the initial array object was empty, when in firebug i clicked on the objects that where shown with the array object (though obviously not being properties of it) the data was there, structured and accessible/ any ideas?